# trying to write a PS script to dump data from multiple .csv into a single csv

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have multiple .csv files in a folder. I am trying to use Powershell to take all of the data in the original csv's and just dump all the columns and data etc into a single .csv

for example

CSV1

```
a,b,c
```

CSV2

```
d,e,f
```

CSV3

```
g,h,i
```

Result

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
```

feel like this is really easy but I'm new to powershell!

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Assuming a,b,c represent Header/Columns - by which means shall the csv files by joined/merged/attached/appended whatsoever?

Comment: First off, show the code that you have tried.
Second, are all the columns the same in each spreadsheet?

Comment: [1] do the source files have more than one row? [2] do they have a header line? [3] what is the relationship between rows in each file - mere row number or some column value?